# Paginate WordPress product list with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I have a similar problem which is mentioned here:
[Ajax Pagination With wordpress query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108948/ajax-pagination-with-wordpress-query)

For the reference I followed the same url's mentioned there, I am stuck with the pagination part on how can I list my products i.e 10 products on one selection and then paginate them with ajax.

I worked out on the code further and got the pagination links working but they are going to the next page, I need ajax to load product under the same page.

I am using following code to query my product and adding pagination links:

```
<?php 

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) :    1;
 $args = array('posts per page' => 10,
 'paged'          => $paged,
 'post_type'    => 'product',
 'post_status'          => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
 );
 $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

 $count = $the_query->found_posts;

 echo $count;
 echo "<br>";

 $total_pages = ceil($count/10);
 echo $total_pages;
 echo "<br>";

  // The Loop
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 echo '<ul>';
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
 }else {
 // no posts found
 }

 wp_reset_postdata();

?>
 <?php

  $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

  echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
 ) );
 ?>
```

I am not sure how to get the ajax for the pagination now to load the list on the same page.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: Hi Ervald, this is what i amusing for the search:
http://www.remicorson.com/woocommerce-list-products-by-attribute-with-multiple-values/

and I want pagination like this:
https://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-pagination/

Comment: Unfortunately that shortcode you're using does not return pagination links and does not support ajax calls.
You'll have to edit it or make your own using the same query but adding [paginate_links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) and use javascript to navigate through the pages by calling [wp_ajax](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Comment: Hi Ervald, thanks for the help, I've updated my code above as you can see that, i can't figure out how to workout on the ajax part of it.